# Use thread-specific pre-allocated data to run tasks in parallel

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, rayon

I want to run some tasks in parallel. Each task uses heap-allocated data. To speed things up, I would like that each thread re-use the same data instead of un-allocating it and re-allocating it just after. Is it feasible?

Here is a basic example of what I want to do:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    // Data for the tasks to run in parallel.
    let tasks: Vec<_> = (0..1000).collect();

    let task_results: Vec<_> = tasks
        .par_iter()
        .map(|task| {
            // Allocate heap-allocated data.
            let data: HashMap<usize, usize> = HashMap::with_capacity(1024);
            // Do something the heap-allocated data and the task.
            // Drop the heap-allocated data and return the result from the task.
            task * 2
        })
        .collect();
}
```

Each task uses a `HashMap` for its computation. The `HashMap` is dropped when the task is done. How can I do it such that each thread uses a single `HashMap` that is cleared before running a new task?

Comment: Do you mean using some kind of object pool? Yeah, this is doable, google "object pool rust". Another idea is to use a thread local HashMap, especially useful with a thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map_with`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.map_with) to create a `HashMap` that will be cloned once for each thread and then passed to your closure:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    // Data for the tasks to run in parallel.
    let tasks: Vec<_> = (0..10).collect();

    let task_results: Vec<_> = tasks
        .par_iter()
        .map_with(
            HashMap::<usize, usize>::with_capacity(1024),
            |data, task| {
                // Clear the data for this run
                data.clear();
                // Do something the heap-allocated data and the task.
                task * 2
            },
        )
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", task_results);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=842b37891a12fc78295135a223c4c26d)